# How to compile a program using static library libdl.a

Tags: c, gcc, libc

I am trying to compile the example code which is using APIs from libdl library:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    void *handle;
    double (*cosine)(double);
    char *error;

   handle = dlopen("libm.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    if (!handle) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", dlerror());
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

   dlerror();    /* Clear any existing error */

   /* Writing: cosine = (double (*)(double)) dlsym(handle, "cos");
       would seem more natural, but the C99 standard leaves
       casting from "void *" to a function pointer undefined.
       The assignment used below is the POSIX.1-2003 (Technical
       Corrigendum 1) workaround; see the Rationale for the
       POSIX specification of dlsym(). */

   *(void **) (&cosine) = dlsym(handle, "cos");

   if ((error = dlerror()) != NULL)  {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", error);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

   printf("%f\n", (*cosine)(2.0));
    dlclose(handle);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I used the following command to compile:
--> gcc -static -o foo foo.c -ldl

I got the following error:

```
foo.c:(.text+0x1a): warning: Using 'dlopen' in statically linked applications requires at runtime the shared libraries from the glibc version used for linking
```

After google, since I am trying to compile it statically, I can find the libdl.a in the lib directory. I am getting the same issue with gethostbyname API also..
What are the other libraries needs to add to compile dl_open statically.

Answer (score 0):

One possible problem:

```
dlsym()
```

Should be declared or implemented *before* it is referenced in **main()**.

Comment: that was typo error. I have included the libdl while compilation. gcc -static -o foo foo.c -ldl

Comment: If anybody have any idea, please help.

Answer (score 0):

dlopen() works only with shared libs. That means that you can't link it statically. Have you tried without `-static` ?

Comment: Yes, it is working fine without -static. Why we can't compile with -static ?

Comment: I am trying to build shared objects statically linked with dlopen,dlsym and dlclose. I have to build this with the help of libdl.a not with -ldl. White trying this ,I got the following error:  /usr/lib64/libdl.a(dlopen.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against undefined symbol `__dlopen' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC.  Any one please help.